# is it haram to celebrate mothers day or fathers day

Tags: halal-haram, celebration

I heard about mothers day and father's day we write letters to them that we love them but my parents said it was haram to celebrate mothers day and fathers day so I just wanted to know if it's true it's haram to celebrate mothers day and fathers day

Comment: can anyone answer to my question

Comment: please anyone reply to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s haram.

1. Because you’re imitating the Kuffar
2. We have 2 holidays: (the 2 Eids)
3. Mother’s and Father’s Day should be everyday, not just one specific day. It doesn’t make sense specifically showering your parents with love and attention on this one day.

Comment: thank you for the answer but brother what do you mean I am imitating kuffar

Comment: @stoneislam doing things that the disbelievers do that were never allowed/part of Islam.

Comment: ok I understand